# Vlookup return two different result

Tags: vlookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcRAN.png)

Data & Result;

If possible to perform vlookup formula the following requirements.

Column A2 to D2 contain order, Type, ID and Reason.

Column F2 to H2 contain Type, ID, Order

In column D3 is ok return the same text in column H3 corresponding to the ranges

if column D3 is expected ok (BBP, KVT, IVT,TTR,) return the type in column H3 corresponding to the ranges.

```
enter code here
```

DATA
Order   TYPE    ID  Reason
02792   88908-13    0060    BBP
02792   88896-13    0220    KVT
02792   88139-03    0140    IVT
02792   88142-03    0300    TTR
02792   88151-03    0200    OK
02792   88154-03    0350    OK

RESULT

TYPE    ID  02792
X88 0060    88908-13
X88 0220    88896-13
X88 0140    88139-03
X88 0300    88142-03
X88 0200    OK
X88 0350    OK

Comment: Do you know about `IF()`?

Comment: Sorry I don't know if.

Comment: Any help for this post

Comment: err.. may I know what formula you had tried?